# How to create mysql stored procedure using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I create a stored procedure using JDBC? I've tried the following code, but it fails with errors.

Contents of the 'sql' variable which is used in jdbc code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'init'()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE '_rollback' BOOL DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET '_rollback' = 1;
    START TRANSACTION;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tst;
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tst
    (
      did    INT          AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
      stage  INT
    );

    INSERT INTO tst (stage) VALUES (11);
    INSERT INTO tst (stage) VALUES (23);

    IF '_rollback'
    THEN
      ROLLBACK;
    ELSE
      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END;
```

JDBC Code:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
statement.executeLargeUpdate(sql);
```

JDBC Error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''create_and_populate_schema'()
  BEGIN
    DECLARE '_rollback' BOOL DEFAULT 0;
 ' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:536)
```

I hope DELIMITER should not be set because it only works inside 'mysql' client and it seems that there is no any alternative with sql-String that is supposed to be used with JDBC

Comment: You are using single quotes for identifiers. use double quotes.

Comment: try directly in MYSQL workbench if it works, then use it in jdbc(Although I am not sure that ppl should be doing this)

Comment: Probably not the cause of the error, but you should use `execute(..)` instead of `executeLargeUpdate(..)` for DDL.